# remove vqcache and opencart 2.3 crash server error 500

Tags: php, opencart2.x, vqmod

i try to restore backup vqcache but still crash, please help!
index.php

```
<?php
/*
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
*/
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: ../install/index.php');
    exit;
}

//VirtualQMOD
require_once('../vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

start('admin');
?>
```

i tried to restore the backup vqcache but still crash, please help!
**please help**

Error log
[09-Feb-2024 10:21:05 Asia/Hong_Kong] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Document::getExtraTags() in /home/dbbeingc/public_html/catalog/controller/event/sb_news.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_action.php(51): ControllerEventSbNews->menu('default/templat...', Array, NULL)
#1 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/system/engine/event.php(23): Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array)
#2 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php(74): Event->trigger('view/common/hea...', Array)
#3 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/catalog/controller/common/header.php(185): Loader->view('default/templat...', Array)
#4 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_action.php(51): ControllerCommonHeader->index(Array)
#5 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php(24): Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array)
#6 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/catalog/controller/error/not_found.php(49): Loader->controller('common/header')
#7 /home/dbbeingc/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system in /home/dbbeingc/public_html/catalog/controller/event/sb_news.php on line 5